# is it possible to emulate previous OS in an Android Device?

Tags: operating-system, emulators

Well, I see no one else have asked this, may be a dummy question, but is it possible (through a menu setting or an app or something) to emulate a previous version of Android OS?

For example, my device is running ICS 4.0.4 and I want it just for a moment to try an app have it in GB 2.3.6 or GB 2.3.3 or even further?

I know about the AVD (Android Virtual Device Manager) but it's just that is not smooth enough for me, that's why I want it in a physical device.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I'm not worried about if an app is supported or not, I'm a developer and what I want to test is the behavior of an app I'm building in different versions of Android. Since I have JB, I want to try my app in ICS and GB to see how it works, minimal details such as action bar that was added in HC. That's why I ask if it's possible to do it with my own device or if I have to get other devices with previous OS

Comment: Well, for the most part, apps built for GB would be compatible under later versions of Android, and also, on later versions of Android, older apps would be compatible. Its a very loaded question you're asking for, depending on the said developer of such an app, they may support older versions of Android or drop it completely.

Comment: It's possible to downgrade, but I'm not so sure about an "emulator".

Comment: Why not use [android x86 emulator](http://www.android-x86.org/), which is *faster* than AVD, AVD uses ARMv7 instruction set which is translated to x86 therefore deemed "slow"?

Comment: Also, have you searched [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) which would be a better audience as its more focused on *development* rather than here! PS You will not be able to get Honeycomb as that's discontinued, closed off, not distributed anymore!

Comment: I'll definately try the x86 emulator, thanks! The question I think belongs in here, because is not a purely programatically question.

Comment: You should try http://www.genymotion.com/